# Iphone App crashes on 4.0 or lower sdk

Tags: iphone, memory, sdk, crash

this crash is happening before i can even break the code anywhere so i cant seem to find out why. i get this error from the console

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKAchievement
  Referenced from: /Users/chris_mellor88/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/D9702DFF-6F6F-4F83-873C-16CE5D3C2861/Match U'm.app/Match U'm
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/GameKit
 in /Users/chris_mellor88/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/D9702DFF-6F6F-4F83-873C-16CE5D3C2861/Match U'm.app/Match U'm
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

As you can see its a Data Formatters error but im not sure why. The app runs perfectly on 4.1 and 4.2 sdk, it just seems to crash on any before that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009959). GKAchievement available Available in iOS 4.1 and later.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access Game Kit (`GKAchievement` class), but it is only available on iOS 4.1 or later.